# Determining the big-O, simplification or not?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am just trying to figure out the runtime of the code below. My thought is that time = log1 + log2 + log3 + ... + log(n-1) = log(n-1)!, but I do not know how to simplify it to big-O.

```c
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j > 0; j /= 2){
        // statement;
    }
}
```

Comment: You got the placement of the factorial wrong, it goes inside the log.

Comment: You should be able to use [some bounds on factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n) to come up with an answer. Looks like n log (n) to me.